# How get attachments in outlook plugin?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Hi how can i get attachments and send it to my java server?
in docs its say:

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
var options = {asyncContext: {currentItem: item}};
item.getAttachmentsAsync(options, callback);

function callback(result) {
  if (result.value.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0 ; i < result.value.length ; i++) {
      result.asyncContext.currentItem.getAttachmentContentAsync(result.value[i].id, handleAttachmentsCallback);
    }
  }
}

function handleAttachmentsCallback(result) {
  // Parse string to be a url, an .eml file, a base64-encoded string, or an .icalendar file.
  switch (result.value.format) {
    case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Base64:
      // Handle file attachment.
      break;
    case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Eml:
      // Handle email item attachment.
      break;
    case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.ICalendar:
      // Handle .icalender attachment.
      break;
    case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Url:
      // Handle cloud attachment.
      break;
    default:
      // Handle attachment formats that are not supported.
  }
}
```

But i have several errors witch this example.
first is `item.getAttachmentsAsync is not a function`
then im tried to use
`result.asyncContext.currentItem.getAttachmentContentAsync(item.attachments[2].id, handleAttachmentsCallback);`

 but its never called calback

How can i get attachments and send them by XMLHttpRequest to my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Mode:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item?view=outlook-js-preview

Compose Mode:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form?view=outlook-js-preview

However, as mentioned in Jadams answer, getAttachmentContentAsync IS supported in Read Mode, and you can get that to the the Base64 encoding of attachments. (the first link will be updated soon to reflect this)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what is happening is that you are trying this code on a read item. The `getAttachmentsAsync` fn only exists in compose mode, so you would see the error above if you are not composing an email. For read emails you should be able to just access the attachments property `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentdetails?view=outlook-js-preview)

Comment: Ok i get all attachment propertis but how get a file?
in my exaplme from question im trying to use it to get an id in getAttachmentsContentAsync but im not i compose mode.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry I think I misread before. `getAttachmentContentAsync` does appear to be supported in read mode. Which api version are you using? This method requires 1.8.

Comment: its only for test, i can use newest wersion. i dont known where to heck actually wersion used by me.  is there any way to get attachments in read mode? or enter a edit mode in js?